# Would my solution work for 8-bit bus addressing using BSRR and BRR?

Tags: stm32, gpio

I have set an 8-bit bus on (PD0:PD7) on the stm32 MCU to send addresses to another chip (0:255). I am interested if a function like below would work for fast change in addresses.  I could not find an example directly showing register to be equal to integer so I want to confirm it would work. I need a function to which I will give an integer value for the address (0:255) and it will set the 8 pins of the bus with this value:

```
void chipbus(uint16_t bus8){
   GPIOD->regs->BSRR = bus8;      // set all the '1' in bus8 to high
   GPIOD->regs->BRR = 255-bus8;   // 255-bus8 inverts the 8 bits
                                  // BRR to set the new '1' to low
}
```

If this solution works, I am curious also if I change the bus to ports PD5:PD12 would my function work as:

```
void chipbus(uint16_t bus8){
   GPIOD->regs->BSRR = bus8*32;      // set all '1' in bus8 to high
                                     // multiply by 32 to shift 5 bits/pins
   GPIOD->regs->BRR = (255-bus8)*32; // 255-bus8 inverts the 8 bits
                                     // BRR to set the new '1' to low
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both should work. However, a more recognisable but equivalent formulation would be:

```
void chipbus(uint16_t bus8) {
  GPIOD->regs->BSRR = bus8; // set all the '1' in bus8 to high
  GPIOD->regs->BRR = (~bus8) & 0xFF; // inverts the 8 bits // BRR to set the new '1' to low
}

void chipbus(uint16_t bus8) {
  GPIOD->regs->BSRR = bus8<<5; // set all '1' in bus8 to high, shift 5 bits
  GPIOD->regs->BRR = ((~bus8)&0xFF)<<5; // inverts the 8 bits
}
```

But, there is an even faster way. BSRR is a 32bit register than can both set and reset. You can combine the two write accesses into one:

```
void chipbus(uint16_t bus8) {
  GPIOD->regs->BSRR =
    (bus8<<5) | (((~bus8) & 0xFF) << (16+5));
}
```

Happy bit-fiddling!

Comment: Wow! And I thought mine is short. Thank you so much! In fact, I guess the fast solution with BSRR only would also fix the problem duskwuff mentions about. Thank you once again!

Comment: Yes, but writes to BSRR also avoid read-modify-write cycles, while the access to ODR is susceptible to write accesses in an ISR that occur right between reading and writing.

Comment: So I think your proposal is the best solution to proceed with. Thank you! I am making custom board and hopefully will have it in a month for real tests...right now just writing the firmware while waiting...

Comment: Test the software with an evaluation board, or else you will have to debug hardware and software simultaneously...

Comment: `GPIOD->regs->BSRR` what is it? Why dont you use standard STM CMSIS definitions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it'd definitely work. However, as others have noted, it's advisable to set the outputs in a single operation.

Taking advantage of the full 32 bit `BSRR` register, it can be done without inverting the data bits:

```
GPIOD->regs->BSRR = bus8 | (0xFF << 16);
```

or

```
GPIOD->regs->BSRR = (bus8 << 5) | (0xFF << (16 + 5));
```

because `BSRR` has the functionality to set some bits and reset some others in a single write operation, and when both the set and reset bits for a particular pin is set, the output becomes `1`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using this approach. Writing to BSRR and BRR as two separate steps means that the bus will transition through an unintended state where some bits are still set from the previous value.

Instead, consider writing directly to the GPIO output data register (ODR). If you need to preserve the original value of the upper bits in the port, you can do that on the CPU side:

```
GPIOD->regs->ODR = (GPIOD->regs->ODR & 0xff00) | (bus8 & 0x00ff);
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I think the above solution using only BSRR would remove the issue you talk about.